# Custom iframe shapes

Tags: iframe

I want to change the shape of the iFrame section from rectangular to my own custom shape:

```
<html>
<body>
<p>dfsdfsdf</p>
<iframe  src="http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-mobile-and-iframes-to-load-external-websites">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iframes` are always rectangular. There's no way to change that.

In general though you might want to look at transparency, z-index and absolute positioning as a possible workaround depending on what you're hoping to achieve.

Answer (score -1):

I agree that iframe are generally regular but you can always take help from some java-script and CSS frameworks to modify your iframe properties.

For example this learning site will provide more detailed information on how to use j-query library to modify iframe.

`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="src/jquery.youtubebackground.js"></script>
````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
    <div id="video"></div>
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

## Call the plugin function and your carousel is ready.

```
$('#video').YTPlayer({
fitToBackground: true,
videoId: 'LSmgKRx5pBo'
});
```

## Need to customize some CSS in order to make it a background

```
#video{
position: relative;
background: transparent;
}

.ytplayer-container{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 z-index: -1;
}
```

#### Works with Youtube Javascript API

#### Youtube Javascript API Options

*Any youtube option must be placed within the playerVars object.*

```
$('#video').YTPlayer({
fitToBackground: true,
videoId: 'LSmgKRx5pBo'
playerVars: {
  modestbranding: 0,
  autoplay: 1,
  controls: 1,
  showinfo: 0,
  branding: 0,
  rel: 0,
  autohide: 0,
  start: 59
}
});
```

**Access all of YouTube's API events and methods by using player:**

```
var player = $('#background-video').data('ytPlayer').player;
player.pauseVideo();
player.playVideo();

player.addEventListener('onStateChange', function(data){
console.log("Player State Change", data);
});
```

## More can be found on this links below::

https://github.com/rochestb/jQuery.YoutubeBackground

https://www.learningjquery.com/2016/03/10-jquery-youtube-plugins